# Signin with apple: On signing in, every time, alert appears with message "Two-factor authentication required". unable to signin

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented signin in with apple. I have used following code for authentication:

```
    //Add button for Sign in with Apple
func setupSOAppleSignIn() {
    let btnAuthorization = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
    btnAuthorization.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
    btnAuthorization.center = self.view.center
    btnAuthorization.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionHandleAppleSignin), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btnAuthorization)
}

// Perform acton on click of Sign in with Apple button
@objc func actionHandleAppleSignin() {
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}
```

I have handle the result with following extensions:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

// ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate function for authorization failed
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

// ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate function for successful authorization
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {

      print("success")
    }
}

}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension ViewController: 
ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
//For present window
func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> 
ASPresentationAnchor {
    return self.view.window!
    }
}
```

Code compiles successfully and I get following this popup:

[pop when signin clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S51ap.png)

I have checked it by signing in with multiple ids.
I have added siginin capability in xcode and set app Id as primary ID on developer console.

Unable figure out the cause. Need help.

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915) to setup Two-factor authentication. This error means you haven't enabled it yet.

Comment: Already enabled.